# (TypeError): this.scrollWhenReady is not a function (Vaadin 14.6.4 + java backend)

Tags: java, typeerror, vaadin14

My problem is to scrollToItem in an in-memory TreeGrid doesn't work.

I tried to use the solution of coockbook (https://cookbook.vaadin.com/scroll-to-item-in-tree-grid), but the scrollToItem doesn't work, and I get a red error with "(TypeError): this.scrollWhenReady is not a function" message.

My question is that "scrollWhenReady" function is available on different name or the coockbook is not useful for Vaadin 14.6.4 version?

Answer (score 1):

The function is defined is specific to this recipe and is defined here:

```
private void initScrollWhenReady() {
            runBeforeClientResponse(
                ui ->
                    getElement()
                        .executeJs(
                            "this.scrollWhenReady = function(index, firstCall){" +
                            "if(this.loading || firstCall) {var that = this; setTimeout(function(){that.scrollWhenReady(index, false);}, 200);}" +
                            "        else {this.scrollToIndex(index);}" +
                            "};"
                        )
            );
        }
```

Did you copy this code and is it executed? It should be executed when the view is attached.

Comment: yes, I copied all functions. The only difference is that I changed T to my entity class.
Also, my TreeGrid uses in-memory, TreeDataProvider.

Comment: The Java function initScrollWhenReady is defining the javascript function scrollWhenReady. So I think the Java function is not called or is called too late. When do you call the scrollToItem function?